# Fallback for jQuery UI from google CDN

Tags: jquery, performance, cdn

Html5 Boilerplate uses the following trick for fallback to locally stored JQuery if grabbing it from Google CDN fails:

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

How would you implement this trick to perform the same trick for jQuery UI?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">!window.jQuery.ui && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="path to jquery UI lib'))</script>
```

Do this after the fallback for jQuery itself.

Or (if you don't like the !)

```
<script type="text/javascript">(window.jQuery.ui === /* notice the === */ undefined) && document.write( /* ... */)</script>
```

[Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript/27531#27531)

Comment: So this should work the same way for any plugin. Great stuff!

Comment: It should. If you don't like the ! you can also test if window.jQuery.ui is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

I do it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using the ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework**

Easier way to do it when you're using bundles.

Get the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` package from NuGet.
Now in your BundleConfig you can setup your bundles to include not only the CdnPath, but also a CdnFallbackExpression:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.UseCdn = true;
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;     
    var jquery = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
    jquery.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery";
    bundles.Add(jquery);
    //...
}
```