# Backup CDN Javascript Library Location

Tags: javascript, firewall, cdn

Our web app uses the Google CDN to link to the jQuery library and it's starting to become very prevalent on our site. We have a major problem every now and then when clients install a firewall and specifically allow *our* website - but they know nothing of these external javascript libraries. It's not a simple case of doing something like checking whether the client can run Javscript - because they can ... they just don't get jQuery and hence functionality is broken.

Is there such a thing as a "backup" JS library where I can specify two locations to check? My other alternative is to provide an FAQ entry for people using a firewall. Hosting the libraries locally isn't really a good idea for us because we're trying to keep bandwidth down, and I like having those libraries elsewhere.

If I include two `<script>` tags it will download them both, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Found here [Fallback for jQuery UI from google CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014040/fallback-for-jquery-ui-from-google-cdn)

Comment: Fantastic thank you. Interesting that the html5 boilerplate did it.